# Azure App Service Application Settings Ignored, Using web.config Instead

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-api

I recently deployed an ASP.Net Web API project to our Azure App Service test slot but started receiving an error when making requests to the API endpoints. Through remote debugging, it became clear that the app was extracting my dev connection strings from the deployed `web.config` file.

The connection strings are *supposed* to come from the Application Settings we set up via the Azure Portal - and, in previous deployments, they were - but that's not the case.

Why would this happen and what can be done to ensure the correct behaviour occurs? We absolutely *don't* want our production database secrets being put into GIT via the `web.config`...

Comment: Are you deploying the project first time to a deployment slot? If yes, you'll have to add the configuration to the application settings of the deployment slot also.

Comment: Can you please post the name of the .NET framework method you are using for reading the configuration?

Comment: @AbhaySaraf - It's using `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["..."].ConnectionString` to read the setting values. I should note that this is ASP.Net Web API 2

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I am encountering the same issue.

Comment: This is working as expected because if  you create a new AppDomain in addition to the AppDomain in which ASP.NET is running already, App-Service-provided app-settings will not be injected correctly.

We inject app-settings using reflection when the app is starting up using an ASP.NET request handler module so that trick will only work for ASP.NET’s app domain(s).

Comment: @RJBreneman Sorry for the late reply. It's been a couple of years since I worked on this and, unfortunately, I can't remember the details.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem too - the problem started sometime after I updated my application to clear the default ASP.NET `IHttpModule` collection - I always thought the Azure App Service App Settings were being added from a Configuration Provider

Comment: @DashleenBhandari-MSFT But thank you for the hint to look for an `IHttpModule`! I opened my Azure App Service's machine-wide `web.config` and my slot's `applicationHost.config` file and I saw references to a `EnvSettings` module! I searched my Azure App Service's filesystem for `EnvSettings.dll` but couldn't find it - I eventually found it in the GAC (where it has a different name). I was able to extricate `EnvSettings.dll` back onto my computer and I'm disassembling it now to find out why it isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

I recently experienced the same problem and fixed it:

- In Azure App Services, the machine-wide `web.config` file is located at `D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config`.
- This file differs to a normal machine-wide `web.config` file because it has this extra element:

  ```
  <system.web>
      ...
      <compilation>
          <assemblies>
              <add assembly="EnvSettings, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
              ...
          </assemblies>
      </compilation>
  </system.web>
  ```
- The `EnvSettings.dll` assembly is located inside `D:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Hosting Framework` (unfortunately this directory is access-controlled and I can't get into it).

  - But `EnvSettings.dll` *is* mirrored in the GAC, so I was able to copy it from there.
- Inside `EnvSettings.dll` is an `[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod]` attribute that runs a method in `EnvSettings.dll` which copiesthe `APPSETTING_` and database connection-string settings from Environment Variables into the .NET Framework `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` and `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` collections.

  - Note this copying only happens **once** (during application startup), and only in the first `AppDomain` - so if you have other `AppDomain` instances in your application they won't see the updated `ConfigurationManager`.
- Therefore, if you see that your Azure Portal configuration settings for your App Service are not being used when you dump your `ConfigurationManager`, then the following is likely happening:

  - You used `<clear />` in your `<compilation><assemblies>` element, which stops `EnvSettings.dll` from being loaded at all.

    - In which case you need to either add back the `<add assembly="EnvSettings...` element from above to your own `web.config`, or find some other way to load it.

      - I don't recommend saving `EnvSettings.dll` locally and adding an assembly reference to your project, as `EnvSettings.dll` is part of the Microsoft Web Hosting Framework.
  - Or you have code that is clearing or resetting `ConfigurationManager` after `EnvSettings` populates it for you.
  - Or something else is going on that I have no idea about!

As an alternative to having `EnvSettings.dll` copy your settings over, another option is to copy the environment-variables over yourself - and as you control the code that does this it means you can call it whenever you need to (e.g. if you ever reset them).

Here's the code I used:

```
public static class AzureAppSettingsConfigurationLoader
{
    public static void Apply()
    {
        foreach( DictionaryEntry environmentVariable in Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables() )
        {
            String name  = (String)environmentVariable.Key;
            String value = (String)environmentVariable.Value;
            
            if( name.StartsWith( "APPSETTING_", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) )
            {
                String appSettingName = name.Substring( "APPSETTING_".Length );
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ appSettingName ] = value;
            }
            else if( name.StartsWith( "SQLAZURECONNSTR_", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) )
            {
                String csName = name.Substring( "SQLAZURECONNSTR_".Length );

                ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Add( new ConnectionStringSettings( csName, value, providerName: ""System.Data.SqlClient" ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

See my sample here: http://mvc5appsettings.azurewebsites.net/

```cs
// My web.config also has a "HERO_TEXT" key in
// that reads "Value from web.config"
string hero = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HERO_TEXT"];
```

[image: Pulling App Settings]

Wiki page on App Settings for .NET:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Managing-settings-and-secrets

As already mentioned here, make sure you have that App Setting in the right slot.

Answer (score -4):

As I know, the settings in Azure portal will override existing setting in Web.config. So If you want to ignore the Azure Application settings in portal and use Web.config instead. I am afraid you need to configure the settings in web.config, and remove the same key/pair in Azure portal.

Comment: I *don't* want to ignore the Azure Application settings - but that's what's happening. I've checked carefully and can confirm that the Azure Application setting keys match up to the values we're using in code.

Comment: This is the opposite of the problem he is having.  The problem he's having is that they're NOT overwriting the web.config settings.